# Replace the string either with sed or awk, where it identifies a patter as mentioned below

Tags: awk, sed

Could u please let know how can I convert the below INPUT into the mentioned OUTPUT using AWK:

**INPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE ${hf:XX_DB_XX}.test_${hf:XX_YYYYMMDD_XX}
AS
SELECT id
FROM ${hf:XX_R_DB_XX}.usr_${hf:XX_YYYYMMDD_XX}
WHERE year              = ${hf:XX_YYYY_XX}
AND month       = ${hf:XX_MM_XX}
AND day         = ${hf:XX_DD_XX};
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE XX_DB_XX.test_XX_YYYYMMDD_XX
AS
SELECT id
FROM XX_R_DB_XX.usr_XX_YYYYMMDD_XX
WHERE year              = XX_YYYY_XX
AND month       = XX_MM_XX
AND day         = XX_DD_XX;
```

Below is what I have used to convert from the given OUTPUT to INPUT.

```
awk '{gsub(/XX_[a-zA-Z]+_XX/,"${hf:&}")} 1' <filename>
```

And to reverse that I tried the below , but did not work out

```
awk '{gsub(/${hf:XX_[a-zA-Z]+_XX}/,"&")} 1' <filename>
```

Comment: @kvantour I just the added the specs that I tried , just missed to mention the same.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` will do here

```
$ sed -E 's/\$\{hf:([^}]+)\}/\1/g' file
```

similarly with GNU `awk`

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/\${hf:([^}]+)}/,"\\1","g")}' file
```

Comment: Thanks that worked . Is there a way to do it in awk, I find it hard to understand the syntax of sed.

Comment: there is no difference in regex, with `awk` you need to type more chars!

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `\{` when using ERE: `sed -E 's/\${hf:([^}]+)}/\1/g'`

Comment: @SLePort you do if you want then to be treated as literal characters as in karakfas script. Given unescaped { and } awk can tell when you're trying to use a RE interval or not but sed assumes the {...} is always intended to be a RE interval and so fails with an error if the text between unescaped { and } isn't a number.

Comment: @EdMorton You're absolutely right about the literal `\{` (I was not completely awaken when I commented). But curiously, using `{`(without escaping) in ERE mode does the job on BSD sed(Mac OS).

Comment: @SLePort Good to know. I'd always escape them anyway for clarity if nothing else of course.